# Why is this code causing a parsing error when using the coalesce operator

Tags: javascript, npm, tsx

I am not sure what I updated in my React project, but I started getting a parsing error trying to build my project.  I am certain (honestly) that this worked fine some time in the recent past.  (source file is a .tsx file)  Thoughts?

```
const titles = new Map<number, string>();
resources.forEach((e: any) => {
    // titles.set(
    //     e.StoreHierarchyValueId ?? e.SkuHierarchyValueId, e.Value
    // )
    if (e.StoreHierarchyValueId)
        titles.set(e.StoreHierarchyValueId, e.Value);
    else
        titles.set(e.SkuHierarchyValueId, e.Value);

    });
```

When I had the commented out code in place, "npm run build" would error out with the following less than helpful (to me) message:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (51:822)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> | //     []
> | // );
> function retrieveCustomerResources(){console.log('"',env,'", "',customer,'"');if(env!==''&&env!==undefined&&customer!==''&&customer!==undefined){setLoadingResources(true);axios.get("/"+props.urlPart+"Hierarchy/"+env+"/"+customer).then(function(response){setResources(response.data);}).catch(function(error){console.log(error);}).then(function(){setLoadingResources(false);});}}if(env==="")return/*#**PURE***/React.createElement("div",null,"No HT environment seleted");if(loadingResources){return/*#**PURE***/React.createElement("div",null,"Loading "+props.urlPart+" Data for..."+customer);}if(resources===null||resources.length===0){return/*#**PURE***/React.createElement("div",null,"No "+props.urlPart+" Data for..."+customer);}var titles=new Map();resources.forEach(function(e){return titles.set(e.StoreHierarchyValueId??e.SkuHierarchyValueId,e.Value);});var parentMap=new Map();resources.forEach(function(f){f.subRows=[];parentMap.set(f.StoreHierarchyValueId??f.SkuHierarchyValueId,f.subRows);});resources.forEach(function(f,_i){var v=parentMap.get(f.ParentId);if(!v){parentMap.set(f.ParentId,[f]);}else{v.push(f);}});var data=resources.filter(function(e){return e.ParentId===0;});// function Table({ columns, data, renderRowSubComponent }
> | //     : { columns: any, data: any, renderRowSubComponent: any }
> | // ): any {

The problematic code was no where near line 51.  The only way I figured this out was by commenting out sections of code until it compiled successfully.

Comment: Presumably because you're not using a tool that understands `??`, so probably talk about which versions of the various tools you're using in your post?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans : That sounds simple and makes sense.  Let me see if I can track that down.  I started a new project (like the original) with "npx create-react-app" to try and repo the problem.  I will start adding in dependencies like the original project and report what I find.  I am using TSLINT which is somewhat new to the project.

Comment: going to either be the compilation target or the browser list support.

Comment: @epascarello - Yup.  My tsconfig file had target set to ES5.  WHen I changed it to ES6, the problem went away.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans and @epascarello.  It was definitely my tooling options.

I was using eslint and typescript.  My .tsconfig file had a target of "es5" (not sure how that got set, but anyways...)  Once I changed it to ES6, the problem naturally went away.